# transform only applied to recycled views in UICollectionView when applied in cellForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Not sure what I am missing here. I am flipping my `UICollectionView` to achieve a bottom first styling expected of chat messages lists. My issue arrises when I try to rotate my message cells. I use transform

`cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: 0)`

in

`collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`

The issue is the first batch of messages dont have the transform applied and render upside down but if I scroll up new messages are rendered with the transformation and are right side up. As I scroll back down the original messages load properly too. Seems like my transform is only applied to recycled views, what do I need to do so that its applied to new and recycled views?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the transform property via the layout attributes. The collection view applies all attributes to a cell usually after getting a cell from it's data source. 
See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayoutattributes for all possible attributes supported by layout attributes.

It's not recommended to modify one of these attributes via code some where else. If you've build your own layout class it should be easy to set the transform property. If you're using UICollectionViewFlowLayout you most likely have to subclass it.

Comment: Thanks for answering and that is currently what I am doing (should have mentioned that sorry) but here is the issue with that approach, you can see the messages being flipped really fast as they are presented on the screen. Can I avoid this some how?

Comment: I am currently using `override open func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? ` and `override open func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?`

Comment: @Osman: I've no idea why this is happening. But maybe you can override `applyLayoutAttributes` in your cell class to be able to debug when and what attributes are applied.